# Display a word or an excel document using javascript

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have a blob for a word and an excel document because I cannot get the direct file path from the server. I cannot use any external JS libraries. Is it possible to preview them without using doc viewer.

Tried to assign type: 'application/pdf' to the blob, but the files are not loading

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: If you have a blob object you _can_ [create a URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL_static) for it on the client side which you could use to open a new tab. I'm not saying this is the best solution for any particular issue.